# result.h264: No such file or directory Cmd

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

So I was basically trying to recover a corrupted mp4 video, and after this line I pasted:

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 160.000 -i result.h264 -i result.aac -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -c:a copy result.mp4
```

I got this:

[image: IMG:]

in ffmpeg.

And I don't understand result.h264. Can you help me solve the error?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. It couldn't find `result.h264`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that file **result.h264** does not exist in your path
**C:\Users\User\Desktop\Recover\bin**.

When you're writing code, after **-i** drag and drop your h264 file directly on the cmd terminal; by doing this you shouldn't get this error anymore.